# Help troubleshoot OS intermittand lockup Ubuntu 22.04.02

Tags: drivers, kernel

PC randomly locks up for no apparent reason. I'm trying to troubleshoot and would appreciate any advice. Bios and all software fully updated. The picture below, is it NVME SSD, CPU, Kernel, driver, etc... related?

[image]

Comment: Does it work when you reboot?

Comment: Works fine after rebooting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having a similar issue, it turned out that the NVME SSD that the supplier promised me was compatible with my device, was not. I replaced it with one of the manufacturer's specified drives, and that solved the issue.